# What is the difference between this fiddle and this web site?

Tags: css

I'm using a fiddle to reproduce a bug, but it always works in the fiddle and not in the web site.

It is simply a horizontal grouping of p tags.

In the fiddle it works fine. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/odx0chnf/1/).

Here is the HTML

```
   <div id='mi_control' class='radius_all'>
      <p id='mi_cover_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Foo &copy;</p>
      <p id='mi_about_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>About</p>
      <p id='mi_privacy_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Privacy</p>
      <p id='mi_team_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Contact</p>
      <p id='mi_arc_l' class='menu_bottom small_dark'>Developers</p>
    </div>
```

However in the web application it does not.  See [here](http://www.arcmarks.com).

I've added in the resets, the common css and the module specific css, as well as what the browser calls user agent css.

Here is a screen shot of the broken CSS in Chrome with the CSS inspector open.

If I can break the fiddle like the web-site is broken than I will know what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are continually using `position: absolute;` for positioning elements. This removes the elements from the document flow and they don't inherit a width unless you set it. If you inspect the `div`'s you'll see that they're all collapsed in width.

Ideally you **do not** want to be using `position: absolute;` for general layout.

I've put an example on jsfiddle to show you what happens with your code when wrapped in another `position: absolute;` You'll see that the floated elements will break onto new lines to take up as little width as possible. It wasn't showing up as an error on your jsfiddle because the parent element was a block and didn't have `position: absolute;` set.

https://jsfiddle.net/odx0chnf/8/

Comment: Just by adding one element like in my jsfiddle will show you it broken https://jsfiddle.net/odx0chnf/8/

Comment: You'll want to consider rebuilding the layout without using `absolute`. It'll be a bit of work but put you in far better stead for developing the site. Have a look at how bootstrap or something similar does it's layout

Comment: A width like @vivekkupadhyay suggested will work. I would only consider this as temporary though.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you:

```
#mi_control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: -17px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: You've used `DOM` elements using `float` property but haven't `clear` it, and also using `position:absolute` doesn't consider a good option to manage `DOM` elements may be i.e. why it creating problem on website but not on `JSFiddle`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is your container `<div id="mi_holder" class="proof_of_existance">` has no height or width, so the div `<div id="mi_control" class="radius_all">` is trying to fit into this space, only expanding to fit the contents.

Since you do not have a container with a fixed width, the text is being wrapped. Meanwhile, the JSFiddle frame is the container for the div and does not need to wrap the text. If you changed the width of the JSFiddle frame to 0, you would see the same issue.

You can solve the issue you are experiencing by changing the width of the `mi_control` div to fit the contents, as shown in another answer.